# What application for illustrated story telling?

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, libreoffice, presentation

I am working on a project with kids to make them narrate and illustrate their own tale on a digital format. There will be several illustrated pages and an audio files of themselves narrating the story.

I looked in to Libre Office Impress, but the embedded audio or audio transitions don't seem to work and there isn't an easy solution to this it seems.

What alternative application do I have to make this project?

Comment: The issue with Libre Office is worked on at http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/23274/how-to-add-audio-to-impress-presentation
Here I am interested in alternative software recommendations only.

Comment: So: the slide/page comes up on the screen, and the narration plays for that page, and then on the next slide a different audio file plays. Right? Sounds interesting.

Comment: Yes, exactly @evilsoup.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a simpler method for this in Ubuntu (yet).

Tupi and Pencil2D are working on getting the audio import capability working (though I'm not sure if there's a basic feature in there yet).

If nothing else, a better method would be to record with Audacity, illustrate with MyPaint / Inkscape / GIMP, and compile them all with PiTiVi / KdenLive / Flowblade / Openshot / Blender.